# Counting the pages in a PDF file

Tags: pdf, pdf-extraction

I know of several tools/libraries that can do this but I want to know if this is possible with just opening up the file as a text file and looking for a keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have a look at this: http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=8153
**Edit**: not work,  may be too old
Found this:

```
public static int GetNoOfPagesPDF(string FileName)
        {
            int result = 0;
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            StreamReader r = new StreamReader(fs);
            string pdfText = r.ReadToEnd();
            System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regx = new Regex(@"/Type\s*/Page[^s]");
            System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection matches = regx.Matches(pdfText);
            result = matches.Count;
            return result;
        }
```

Ps: tested! It works.[see here](http://www.devasp.net/net/articles/display/726.html)
[source](http://www.devasp.net/SourceCode/726_PdfPageCount.zip)

Comment: FYI - PDF can be written such that you can append changes to the document to the existing file, so if you "delete" pages by appending a new catalog with fewer pages (leaving the old pages in place), this solution will produce incorrect results.

Comment: The above code didn't work for me, returning more than the correct number of pages. But it made me realize that much of a pdf is text and I was able to find it with Regex (non-global match) `/Type /Pages\nCount ([0-9]+)`.

Answer (score 1):

[Edit: based on the edited question]

It is possible by reading it as text file and some minimal parsing.

If you read the pdf yourself then you will need to do the parsing. Each page in a PDF is represented by a page object.

The following provides an understanding about the pdf specification in short for pages and the link to the pdf spec.

- http://help.4xpdf.com/questions/8/how-to-programmatically-count-the-number-of-pages-in-a-pdf

Comment: Preferring pinichi's answer as it has working code.  Voting up your answer because it's very helpful.

Answer (score -1):

The xpdf utilities package (called xpdf-utils in debian) includes an application called pdfinfo. It will print out the number of pages in the file, among other data.

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/how-to-find-pdf-page-count-699113/

Comment: Sorry, not what I'm looking for.  Edited my question's description to clarify further.